# How to correctly customise search.get.js in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I'm using Alfresco Enterprise 6.2. Actual changes I need to make belongs to the [search.lib.js](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share-services/src/main/resources/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.lib.js)
This is an import in the [search.get.js](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share-services/src/main/resources/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js).  I tried modifying `search.lib.js` itself and had no effect. So I populated the import in the `search.get.js` and modified it directly. I'm not too sure if it's the right approach. What would be the best way to go about this change?

Comment: How did you rebuild the JS after making your change? How are you packaging your change?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am placing the search.get.js in alfresco/extension/templates/org/alfresco/slingshot/search path.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your files to below location to override.

alfresco\extension\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\slingshot\search

Answer (score 1):

The approach to overriding web scripts via the alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js path has not changed in 6.2 and is still viable.